# Having issues with applying GCP terraform network code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm getting this error when I do a `terraform apply` but not a `plan`. I'm not sure what I am missing. I have ran a `terraform validate` and it was clean. From searching all the information I found online is from old versions of terraform, I'm using v1.5.4

```
module.vpc_module.google_compute_subnetwork.nl_subnet_private_subnet: Creation complete after 25s [id=projects/wms-prod-388716/regions/us-west1/subnetworks/nl-subnet-private-subnet]
module.vpc_module.google_compute_router.nl_subnet_private_router: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for network: project: required field is not set
│
│   with module.vpc_module.google_compute_route.nl_subnet_private_egress_internet,
│   on ../../modules/vpc_module/vpc.tf line 19, in resource "google_compute_route" "nl_subnet_private_egress_internet":
│   19: resource "google_compute_route" "nl_subnet_private_egress_internet" {

│ Error: Invalid value for network: project: required field is not set
│
│   with module.vpc_module.google_compute_router.nl_subnet_private_router,
│   on ../../modules/vpc_module/vpc.tf line 25, in resource "google_compute_router" "nl_subnet_private_router":
│   25: resource "google_compute_router" "nl_subnet_private_router" {
│
```

Here is the terraform code:

```
resource "google_compute_route" "nl_subnet_private_egress_internet" {
 name             = "prod-egress-internet"
 dest_range       = "0.0.0.0/0"
 network          = google_compute_network.nl_prod.name
 next_hop_gateway = "default-internet-gateway"
 priority    = 100
}
resource "google_compute_router" "nl_subnet_private_router" {
  name    = "nl-subnet-private-router"
  region  = google_compute_subnetwork.nl_subnet_private_subnet.region
  network = google_compute_network.nl_prod.name
}
resource "google_compute_router_nat" "nl_nat_router" {
  name                               = "${google_compute_subnetwork.nl_subnet_private_subnet.name}-nat-router"
  router                             = google_compute_router.nl_subnet_private_router.name
  region                             = google_compute_router.nl_subnet_private_router.region
  nat_ip_allocate_option             = "AUTO_ONLY"
  source_subnetwork_ip_ranges_to_nat = "LIST_OF_SUBNETWORKS"

  subnetwork {
    name                    = google_compute_subnetwork.nl_subnet_private_subnet.name
    source_ip_ranges_to_nat = ["ALL_IP_RANGES"]
  }

  log_config {
    enable = true
    filter = "ERRORS_ONLY"
  }
}
```

Here is the rest of the VPC.tf code for reference:

```
resource "google_compute_network" "nl_prod" {
  project                 = var.project_id
  name                    = "${var.project_id}-vpc"
  auto_create_subnetworks = false
  routing_mode            = "GLOBAL"
  delete_default_routes_on_create = true
}

# Subnet Private
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "nl_subnet_private_subnet" {
  name          = "nl-subnet-private-subnet"
  region        = "us-west1"
  network       = google_compute_network.nl_prod.name
  project       = var.project_id
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/24"
  role          = "ACTIVE"
}
```

Comment: Specify the Project ID for the `project` argument for the resource `google_compute_router`. See this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_router.html#project). However, possibly a better solution is to specify the Project Id at the Google Provider level. See this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference.html) for an example.

Comment: Thank you!!  That did it.. I'm not able to upvote your comment, getting an error..